# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary fai lure in name resolution

Tags: php, image, docker, dockerfile, symfony5

I have this error since three days & I tried to know the reason, but I couldn't. I'm beginner in Docker & Symfony.
I made docker containers for php, mysql & nginx in my project directory from this [Tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/get-started-docker-symfony) , then I installed symfony 5.

When I try to execute the following command inside docker container, where is my project:

```
bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

[the error after the executing of the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Ng0.png)

my directory it's like this:

- symfony_docker

  - app (dir)

    - symfony files are here
  - mysql (dir)
  - nginx (dir)

    - default.conf (file)
  - php (dir)

    - Dockerfile (file)
  - docker-compose.yml (file)

  that is the content of the docker-compose.yml (file)

```
version: '3.3'

services:
 database:
   container_name: database
   image: mysql:8.0
   restart: always
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
     MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony_docker
     MYSQL_USER: symfony
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
   ports:
     - '4306:3306'
   volumes:
     - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
   
   
     php:
       container_name: php
       build:
         context: ./php
       ports:
         - '9000:9000'
       volumes:
         - ./app:/var/www/symfony_docker
   
       depends_on:
         - database
   
     nginx:
       container_name: nginx
       image: nginx:stable-alpine
       ports:
         - '8080:80'
       volumes:
         - ./app:/var/www/symfony_docker
         - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
       depends_on:
         - php
         - database
```

That is the content of the php Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN apt update \
   && apt install -y zlib1g-dev g++ git libicu-dev zip libzip-dev zip \
   && docker-php-ext-install intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql \
   && pecl install apcu \
   && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
   && docker-php-ext-configure zip \
   && docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony_docker

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash
RUN mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
RUN git config --global user.email "test@test.com" \
   && git config --global user.name "test"
```

the content of the default.conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/symfony_docker/public;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \\.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

content of .env in symfony

```
# In all environments, the following files are loaded if they exist,
# the latter taking precedence over the former:
#
#  * .env                contains default values for the environment variables needed by the app
#  * .env.local          uncommitted file with local overrides
#  * .env.$APP_ENV       committed environment-specific defaults
#  * .env.$APP_ENV.local uncommitted environment-specific overrides
#
# Real environment variables win over .env files.
#
# DO NOT DEFINE PRODUCTION SECRETS IN THIS FILE NOR IN ANY OTHER COMMITTED FILES.
#
# Run "composer dump-env prod" to compile .env files for production use (requires symfony/flex >=1.2).
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-environment-variables-for-infrastructure-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=ace4f16ab212b0206302e83d3939664f
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"

DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:secret@mysql:4306/menukarte?serverVersion=5.7"

###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

I tried already to change the DATABASE_URL= to

1. @mysql
2. @localhost
3. @27.0.0.1
   no one of them resolved the issue

thank you very much

Comment: Did you try use "database" as host ?

Comment: Do you mean like this:
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:secret@database:4306/menukarte?serverVersion=5.7"


When you mean this.
I tried it now & I recieved the following error:

 "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused"

Comment: wohooo, thank you very much now it's work :)

Comment: I added the host as you said,
and I changed the port to 3306

Like this:

 DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:secret@database:3306/menukarte?serverVersion=5.7"

Comment: Please start by extracting a [mcve], which is required for your question to be on-topic. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: BTW: Do any of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQLSTATE+HY000+2002+php_network_getaddresses%3A+getaddrinfo+failed%3A+Temporary+failure+in+name+resolution give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I added the host as you said, and I changed the port to 3306 Like this: DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:secret@database:3306/menukarte?serverVersion=5.7" –

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31094833)